# Bad escapement JSHint

Tags: javascript, jshint

Does anybody know why I get a `Bad escapement` error on JSHint using the follow code?

```
var regexS = '[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)';
```

Answer (score 6):

Just double escape the `\`

```
var regexS = '[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)';
```

Even though I'm guessing you'll be using this string for a `Regex` object, characters in a string must be escaped correctly. By default, a `\` attempts to escape the next character. If you add an extra one to be like `\\`, it escapes the original `\` and evaluates to a single `\` in the final string.

Answer (score 4):

\? isn't a valid escape character. Try replacing it with \\.

So it looks like:

```
var regexS = '[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)';
```

Keep in mind that "\" escapes the character that comes after it.  This is why \\ comes out as a single slash (if you look at the source of this question you will find I needed to quadruple the \).

Other common escape sequences are \n for newline and \t for tab.